# Functional test skip authorization WebApplicationFactory OIDC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, functional-testing

Goal: Create functional tests with mocked access token but skipped authorization (not calling the endpoint). Testing controller methods of my web API. The API is protected by authentication/authorization via access token (bearer). Communicating with out identity server 4.

Currently: Created my custom WebApplicationFactory, database gets seeded, access token gets created.

Problem: Tests are failing when the identity server 4 is not running. I don't know how to exactly mock the identity server. The self created access token is working. If the identity server is running the test are passing with authorization.

MockJwtToken.cs

```cs
public static class MockJwtToken
    {
        public static string Issuer { get; } = "https://localhost:5001";
        public static string Audience { get; } = "https://localhost:5001/resources";
        public static SecurityKey SecurityKey { get; }
        public static SigningCredentials SigningCredentials { get; }

        private static readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler STokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        private static readonly RandomNumberGenerator SRng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        private static readonly byte[] SKey = new byte[32];

        static MockJwtToken()
        {
            SRng.GetBytes(SKey);
            SecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(SKey) { KeyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(SecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        }

        public static string GenerateJwtToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
        {
            return STokenHandler.WriteToken(new JwtSecurityToken(Issuer, Audience, claims, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20), SigningCredentials));
        }

        public static string GenerateJwtTokenAsUser()
        {
            return GenerateJwtToken(UserClaims);
        }

        public static List<Claim> UserClaims { get; set; } = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, "test"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "test@test.com"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "openid"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "api.com:read"),
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "api.com:write"),
        };
    }
```

Thats my custom WebApplicationFactory

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = "DataSource=:memory:";
        private readonly SqliteConnection _connection;

        public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
        {
            _connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
            _connection.Open();
        }

        protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var host = builder.Build();

            var serviceProvider = host.Services;

            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
                var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();
                var dbInit = new DbInitializer(context);

                try
                {
                    dbInit.MigrateDatabase();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred seeding the " + $"database with test messages. Error: {e.Message}");
                }

                try
                {
                    dbInit.SeedAllEnums();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred seeding the " + $"database with test messages. Error: {e.Message}");
                }
            }

            host.Start();
            return host;
        }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot("src/Project.Api.Web")
                .ConfigureTestServices(ConfigureServices)
                .UseEnvironment("Testing");
        }

        protected virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<DbContext>));

            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(descriptor);
            }

            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = CreateTokenValidationParameters();
                options.Audience = MockJwtToken.Audience;
                options.Authority = MockJwtToken.Issuer;
            });

            // Add ApplicationDbContext using an in-memory database for testing.
            services
                .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
                .AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlite(_connection);
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());
                });
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            _connection.Close();
        }

        private TokenValidationParameters CreateTokenValidationParameters()
        {
            TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = MockJwtToken.SecurityKey,

                SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
                {
                    JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

                    return jwt;
                },
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireSignedTokens = false,
            };

            return tokenValidationParameters;
        }

    }
```

Also using a Extension for my HttpClient to parse the responses.
This is my first simple test class:

```cs
[TestClass]
    public class ClientsControllerTest
    {
        private static CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
        private static HttpClient _client;
        private static IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
        private static IServiceScope _scope;
        private static DbContext _context;
        private static IDbInitializer _dbInit;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInit(TestContext testContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testContext.TestName);
            _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
            _scopeFactory = _factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            _scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
            _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>();
            _dbInit = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbInitializer>();
            _client = _factory.CreateClient();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetAllAsync_NoData_ReturnsEmptyListWithOk()
        {
            //arrange

            _dbInit.SeedClients();
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            string at = MockJwtToken.GenerateJwtTokenAsUser();

            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + at);

            //act
            HttpParsedResponseMessage<ClientModel[]> msg;
            ClientModel[] clients;

            try
            {

                msg = await _client.GetAsync<ClientModel[]>("/api/clients");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }

            clients = msg.ParsedObject;

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, msg.ResponseMessage.StatusCode);
            Assert.AreEqual("application/json; charset=utf-8", msg.ResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString());

            Assert.AreEqual(1, clients?.Length);
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup()
        {
            _factory.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

When starting the test, the service tries to communicate with my identity server. I simple want to mock this away. That is also what the stack trace is telling me:

> !
> GetAllAsync_NoData_ReturnsEmptyListWithOk
> 2021-04-23 10:42:44,977 [4] INFO  - Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
> 2021-04-23 10:42:45,033 [4] INFO  - Hosting environment: Testing
> 2021-04-23 10:42:45,034 [4] INFO  - Content root path: C:\repos\project\Project.Api\src\Project.Api.Web
> 2021-04-23 10:43:02,901 [8] ERROR - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.ProblemDetailsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> !

Comment: Create a bearer token that has an expiry date of 2100, and put that in your test.

Comment: @Neil why should this help in avoiding to communicate with the identity server?

Comment: You communicate with the identity server to get a bearer token that you need to access the API.   If you already have the bearer token, then you can just talk directly to the API.

Comment: If your API is communicating with the identity server to verify your bearer token, then your authentication is broken.

Comment: So the AT may not be valid?

Comment: It looks like your middleware at `Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.ProblemDetailsMiddleware.Invoke` is deciding to call the authentication server.  I'd be checking why that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, I needed to also override the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration` within the `JwtBearerOptions`

```cs
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = CreateTokenValidationParameters();
    options.Audience = MockJsonWebToken.Audience;
    options.Authority = MockJsonWebToken.Issuer;
    options.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration()
    {
        Issuer = MockJsonWebToken.Issuer,
    };
});
```

After this changes I could turn of my internet connection and the service wasn't longer trying to communicate to any issuer.

So here again my full own CustomWebApplicationFactory.

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    private readonly string _connectionString = "DataSource=:memory:";
    private readonly SqliteConnection _connection;

    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        _connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var host = builder.Build();

        var serviceProvider = host.Services;

        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
            var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();
            var dbInit = new DbInitializer(context);

            try
            {
                dbInit.MigrateDatabase();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred seeding the " + $"database with test messages. Error: {e.Message}");
            }

            try
            {
                dbInit.SeedAllEnums();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred seeding the " + $"database with test messages. Error: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        host.Start();
        return host;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot("src/Project.Api.Web")
            .ConfigureTestServices(ConfigureServices)
            .UseEnvironment("Testing");
    }

    protected virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<DbContext>));

        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            services.Remove(descriptor);
        }

        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = CreateTokenValidationParameters();
            options.Audience = MockJsonWebToken.Audience;
            options.Authority = MockJsonWebToken.Issuer;
            options.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration()
            {
                Issuer = MockJsonWebToken.Issuer,
            };
        });

        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
            .AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite(_connection);
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());
            });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _connection.Close();
    }

    private TokenValidationParameters CreateTokenValidationParameters()
    {
        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = MockJsonWebToken.SecurityKey,

            SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
            {
                JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

                return jwt;
            },
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            RequireSignedTokens = false,
        };

        return tokenValidationParameters;
    }

}
```

The MockJwtToken wasnt changed further. Just renamed here to MockJsonWebToken because of JwtToken was kind of redundant.